# Something I don't understand with electricity and my circuit

Tags: serial, atmega

My title is strange, but my circuit is acting weird and I hope someone can explain me this strange behavior.

I have made a simple circuit with an ATmega which send output to the TX pin, and my USB to serial is receiving the data. The TX output is only working when I touch some metallic part of my circuit. The rest of the time this is not working.

[image]

[image]

For example, if I touch any of one of my LED pin, or one of the capacitor pin, a resistor or even my voltage regulator, my circuit is actually working great. If I stop touching it, it doesn't work anymore.

Here you can see the picture of my circuit, and the second image when I touch the voltage regulator, the RX LED of my FT232R is blinking, at the same rate at the TX data. (I send data each 100ms).

I have already checked the source voltage, and it is a nice 5V. My FT232R is sourced from the USB of my laptop and the only connection to the circuit is from TX pin from ATmega to his RX pin.

If I post the question, is that I have actually no mean to explain that. The fact is the circuit should work of course without my body. I have tried to change the source voltage to 3.3V and this is the same behavior.

Can someone can explain me what to do in order to make my circuit working? If I reset my FT232R (unplugging / replugging it), it works as expected few seconds. But after nothing happens at all.

This makes me very perplexed.

Comment: Connect the FT232R ground to the bigger breadboard ground.

Comment: You have a floating ground.

Comment: @Vladimir You should post as an answer so the question can be marked as answered (but also to get internet points!).

Comment: internet points ftw! yay!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just connect the usb-to-serial converter ground and the ATmega ground together. Since the two circuits are powered by two different sources there is no guarantee that their references are at the same potential, so the communication do not happen properly. When you touch the ATmega board you actually stabilize the reference in some ways so the circuit works.

Not connecting grounds together is a common mistake and apart from not working circuits can lead to more catastrophic failures. The rule is: **always** connect ground **first**, and if you want to unpower a part of your circuit just leave the ground connection there, removing only the "hot" power is faster, easier and safer.

Comment: Really thank you @Vladimir. I actually learn much today. It first looks like magic when you don't understand the physic beyond. It feels like I have could spend days to understand what happened without your help

Comment: I have spent many days (!) understanding simpler things, just don't be afraid to experiment, learn and ask.